# VUEJS is resetting my form to default value after update on form values

Tags: php, vue.js

I have a form with datepicker input and checkboxes.
After I have updated the value for datepicker and will check a checkbox, the value on the datepicker returns to its default value.

Can any one help me?

Note: I am using vue.js in a PHP file

Here's the code on my form

```
<form id="Create_Weekly_Payment_Form" action="lib/raw-operations/customer_transactions.php " method="POST" autocomplete="off">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 mt-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Sale_Week">Sale Week</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Sale_Week" placeholder="Enter Sale Week" v-model="form.Sale_Week" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 mt-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Pay_Week">Pay Week</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Pay_Week" placeholder="Enter Pay Week" v-model="form.Pay_Week" required />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="mt-4">Sales Representatives</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3" v-if="sales_reps.length > 0">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="Select_All" @change="selectAllSalesRep($event)" v-model="All_Selected">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="Select_All">
                        Select All
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3" v-for="(sales_rep, sales_rep_key) in sales_reps">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" :id="'cx_sales_rep_'+sales_rep_key" v-model="form.Selected_Sales_Rep_IDs" :value="sales_rep.Sales_Rep_ID" @change="addSalesRep(sales_rep_key, sales_rep, $event)">
                    <label class="form-check-label" :for="'cx_sales_rep_'+sales_rep_key">
                        {{ sales_rep.Name }}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div v-for="snumber_input in form.Selected_Sales_Rep" v-html="snumber_input.html" v-if="snumber_input.Sales_Rep_ID === sales_rep.Sales_Rep_ID">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my VUEJS code (not full code but I think this is what matters)

```
const vueApp = new Vue({
el: '#vapp',
data () {
    return {
        page_title: 'Create Weekly Payment',
        sales_reps: sales_reps,
        form: {
            Selected_Sales_Rep: [],
            Selected_Sales_Rep_IDs: [],
            Sale_Week: moment().startOf('isoweek').subtract(14, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            Pay_Week: moment().startOf('isoweek').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            Payment_Summary_Numbers: [],
        },
        All_Selected: false,
    }
},
methods: {
    addSalesRep(sales_rep_key, sales_rep, $event) {
        this.All_Selected = false;
        if ($event.target.checked) {
            this.addSummaryNumberInput(sales_rep_key, sales_rep);
        } else {
            this.form.Selected_Sales_Rep = $.grep(this.form.Selected_Sales_Rep, function(e){
                return e.Sales_Rep_ID != sales_rep.Sales_Rep_ID;
            });
        }
    },
    selectAllSalesRep($event) {
        this.form.Selected_Sales_Rep_IDs = [];
        this.form.Selected_Sales_Rep = [];
        if (this.All_Selected) {
            this.sales_reps.forEach((sales_rep, sales_rep_key) => {
                this.form.Selected_Sales_Rep_IDs.push(sales_rep.Sales_Rep_ID.toString());
                this.addSummaryNumberInput(sales_rep_key, sales_rep);
            });
        } else {
        }
    },
    addSummaryNumberInput(sales_rep_key, sales_rep) {
    },
    async submitWeeklyPayment() {
    },
},
created() {},
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion when using objects. Instead of `push()` you should use `Vue.Set()`.

For further information read about [Reactivity in VueJs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer but even if I remove the push() the value on the datepicker is still returning to default value when I check a checkbox. This is also happening on my other pages after I have selected a value on a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a fixed :key when v-for loops - Vue isn't able to keep track of what is what because Vue uses an "in-place-patch" strategy which is pretty much using index as a reference so when your render output relies on temporary state like input values, it fails.

More on: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State

In your code: `v-for="(sales_rep, sales_rep_key) in sales_reps">` add the :key attribute and bind it to the id. What you have named sale_rep_key is not an actual key but the index in the loop and should not be used as key. I would also suggesting naming that to simply index to avoid confusion.

So your for-loop should be:

`v-for="(sales_rep, index) in sales_reps" :key="sales_rep.Sales_Rep_ID">`